# Java: Interpreting UTF-8 in a Java program

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

My program is receiving an integer array from a browser application that's interpreted as UTF-8 (example in code). I can echo my resulting string ("theString" shown in the code below) back to the browser and everything's fine. But it's not fine in the Java program. The input string is "Hällo". But it prints out from the Java program as "Hõllo".

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class TestCode {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

      // H : 72
      // ä : 195 164
      // l : 108
      // o : 111
      // the following is the input sent from browser representing String = "Hällo"
      int[] utf8Array = {72, 195, 164, 108, 108, 111};

      String notYet = new String(utf8Array, 0, utf8Array.length);
      String theString = new String(notYet.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

      System.out.println(theString);
   }
}
```

Comment: @tchrist: Yeah; don't use `int[]`s.  Instead, use string literals or `byte[]`s

Comment: Thanks everybody .... solutions below confirmed. It still doesn't print properly to the console using System.out.println() -.. but I confirmed it using if (theString.equals("Hällo") ....

Comment: @Slaks no it isn’t that. The point is that he shouldn’t have let the encoded raw byte string leak into his main program in the first place. It should have just been a normal Java Unicode string comprising a sequence of abstract code points. Somewhere someone forgot to decode the raw buffer into a normal string.

Comment: @tchrist: Exactly. That's what I meant by `Instead, use string literals`

Comment: @Roger: You have to decode all bytewise binary input into normal Java strings before you can deal with them as strings. I do not know where your data is really coming from, but they are evil for giving you byte data not character data. You will have to decode it yourself if the library is broken. On the way out, send it through an OutputStreamWriter that has a UTF encoding on it and you will be fine.

Comment: It's based on a standard that wants to pass a smaller amount of data over the internet, to reduce congestion. App writers at both ends have no choice in the matter.

Comment: Interesting side-note. I'm testing on Linux now. I hadn't put a lot of effort into System.out.println for internationalization; so Chinese characters (for example) just produced strange (not Chinese) characters when printed to a command window (Windows). In Linux, they actually print out in Chinese. First time I've seen that in a command window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
int[] utf8Array = {72, 195, 164, 108, 108, 111};
byte[] bytes = new byte[utf8Array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < utf8Array.length; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = (byte) utf8Array[i];
}
String theString = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The problem with passing `int[]` directly is that the `String` class interprets every `int` as a separate char, while after converting to `byte[]` `String` treats input as raw bytes and understands that `195, 164` is actually is a single character consisting of two bytes rather than two characters.

UPDATE: Answering your comment, unfortunately, Java *is* that verbose. Compare it to Scala:

```
val ints = Array(72, 195, 164, 108, 108, 111)
println(new String(ints map (_.toByte), "UTF-8"))
```

Once again the difference between `int` and `byte` is not just the compiler being picky, they really mean different things when it comes to UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: This cannot be the easiest and best way to deal with these things.  Please :(

Comment: No, I mean that he has a byte string encoded in UTF-8 and wants it turned into an abstract Unicode string in Java for further processing. The first rule of Unicode is immediately decode on the way in as the first thing you do with your data, but he somehow forgot to do that.  You should be able to do some sort `String s = utf8_to_Unicode(raw_buffer)` function without this monkeybusiness. You certainly shouldn’t be initializing some array.  Something is just bizarre. Then for output he should just send his abstract string to something whose encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: I'd like to decode the data as it comes in but can't find a combination to get the job done. That's a big reason I posted a question. I've been looking, believe me. As for initializing an array, depends on which array you're talking about. I created int[] utf8Array just to simplify illustration of the problem here. The data is actually coming in via an InputStream. InputStream does not have a constructor that includes encoding specification. When I try to use methods on input buffers and such, I keep ending up with "you can't get there from here." It's like Java's designed to make this hard.

Answer (score 3):

You need to feed it with bytes instead of ints so that you can use the `String` constructor taking the charset as argument:

```
byte[] utf8Array = {72, (byte) 195, (byte) 164, 108, 108, 111};
String theString = new String(utf8Array, 0, utf8Array.length, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This seems like a horrible way to do things.  Is there nothing better?

Comment: @thrist: You could omit offset and length arguments which are unnecessary in this context, or use a different (weak typed?) programming language.

Comment: No, I meant that everyone seems to be missing the point. He has encoded data and he should have decoded data.

Comment: @tchrist: True, I was just answering the concrete question directly without actually understanding what the OP is *actually* trying to do as s/he left those details out :)

Comment: I think that's what's been discussed. I end up with decoded data, which is exactly what I was trying to do. If you find a simpler way, please let me know. Feel free to start with an input stream that's delivering bytes in UTF-8. Note that characters may be represented by one, two, or three bytes; just depends on the character.